# Meaning of the perl syntax construction involving a comma

Tags: perl, perlsyn

I've encountered a piece of code in a book that looks like this:

```
#for (some_condition) {
#do something not particularly related to the question
$var = $anotherVar+1, next if #some other condition with $var
#}
```

I've got no clue what does the comma (",") between **$anotherVar+1** and before **next** do. How is this syntax construction called and is it even correct?

Comment: You mean the [comma operator](http://blogs.perl.org/users/steven_haryanto/2012/09/the-comma-operator.html)? You can use it as an alternate statement separator which is what seems to be happening here, but it's not the best idea. Use `;` and a new statement instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
$x=1;
$y=1;

$x++ , $y++ if 0; # note the comma! both x and y are one statement
print "With comma: $x $y\n";

$x=1;
$y=1;

$x++ ; $y++ if 0; # note the semicolon! so two separate statements

print "With semicolon: $x $y\n";
```

The output is as follows:

```
With comma: 1 1
With semicolon: 2 1
```

A comma is similar to a semicolon, except that both sides of the command are treated as a single statement.  This means that in a situation where only one statement is expected, both sides of the comma are evaluated.

Answer (score 5):

The comma operator is described in [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop). You can use it to separate commands, it evaluates its left operand first, then it evaluates the second operand. In this case, the second operand is [next](http://p3rl.org/next) which changes the flow of the program.

Basically, this is a shorter way of writing

```
if ($var eq "...") {
    $var = $anotherVar + 1;
    next
}
```

The comma can be used in a similar way in C, where you can find it often in for loops:

```
for (i = 0, j = 10; i < 10; i++, j--)
```

Comment: I prefer the longer version (using a block with one statement per line). If you crammed 2 statements into the “if”, chances are high that you will need to add more. The longer form is more clear and maintainable.

Comment: @Timur Shtatland, Even worse is that it hides a flow control change (`next`).

Answer (score 3):

The comma is [an operator](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Comma-Operator), in any context. In list context where it's usually seen, it is one way to concatenate values into a list. Here it is being used in scalar context, where it runs the preceding expression, the following expression, and then returns the following expression. This is a holdover from how it works in C and similar languages, when it's not an argument separator; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/comma-operator?view=vs-2019.

```
my @stuff = ('a', 'b'); # comma in list context, forms a list and assigns it
my $stuff = ('a', 'b'); # comma in scalar context, assigns "b"
my $stuff = 'a', 'b'; # assignment has higher precedence
                      # assignment done first then comma operator evaluated in greater context
```